# $\arg\min_{a, b ~\in~ \mathbb{R}} c \left( (ax_1 + b - y_1)^2 \right) ~+~ d ~+~ \cdots ~+~ c\left( (ax_n + b - y_n)^2 \right) + d$

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Is there any efficient algorithm to find parameters $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ that minimize the type of expressions as listed below?

$$\arg\min_{a, b ~\in~ \mathbb{R}} c \left( (ax_1 + b - y_1)^2 \right) ~+~ d ~+~  \cdots ~+~ c\left( (ax_n + b - y_n)^2 \right) + d$$

where $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what is the correct way of writing it in a matrix form right now, so I at least changed the case of the scalars.

Comment: $$
f(\mu) = \alpha \mu + \beta,\ \ \ \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}
$$

$$
f(u)+f(v) = f(u+v)
$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, thank you.

Comment: Take Cesareo's suggestion and write the cost function without any mention of $f$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Did you mean something along the lines of this?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think I'm getting the point: it can be reduced to standard linear regression, right?

Comment: OK, I think it should be clear now that $f$ was not meant to be a linear map (as @Cesareo assumed), but only a linear function.

Comment: Right. Looks like weighted least-squares to me.